# Reset password emails in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am using the django auth views for password reset and setup the Email settings using smtp in settings.py. I am not sure why I am not receiving emails in my gmail. When I send it using the send_mail() function, I am getting emails fine. Does anybody has any idea?

I have configured EMAIL settings in settings.py and added URLs in url.py and made my own template files.

**Settings.py:**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PWD')
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

 path('password-reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

I go to the password_reset and enter my email and click Submit. It shows me password_reset_done page but I do not receive any email in my gmail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in settings.py you are adding the django mail backend so you will receive the mail but in the server screen !!
to receive the message in gmail you need to replace your settings with this settings

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youremail@gmail.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

make sure to replace this settings and add your gmail and password

and you need to allow less secure apps in your gmail account from this link
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1

if it still not working disable the captcha from here
https://accounts.google.com/displayunlockcaptcha
hope this helps

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I tried this but still do not receive emails in gmail

Comment: you did all the steps !! allow less secure mode and disable captcha and added you gmail settings in django settings.py !!??

Answer (score 0):

When he says your password. You've got to log into your Gmail console area and set up an app password, it should be 16 digits long and that's what you use